# Decode sounding data for sonar view of sl2 file in R

Tags: file, binary, sonarqube, decoding

After reading a lot of posts regarding how to analyse the data collected with recreative sonars like Lowrance using .sl2 Sonar Log formarts, I was able to use the read_sl2 function of the arabia package to extract depth data from sl2 files.

I also slightly modified the function to extract more data and convert some values to international units.

```
read_sl2 <- function(path, verbose=TRUE) {
  
  f <- file(path.expand(path), "rb")
  dat <- readBin(f, "raw", n = file.size(path.expand(path)), endian="little")
  close(f)
  
  # read in the header
  header <- readBin(dat, what = "raw", n = 10)
  
  format <- readBin(header[1:2], "int", size=2, endian="little", signed=FALSE)
  
  if (!(format %in% 1:3)) stop("Invalid 'format' in header; Likely not an slg/sl2/sl3 file")
  
  ok_formats <- c("slg", "sl2", "sl3")
  if (verbose) message("Format: ", ok_formats[format])
  
  version <- readBin(header[3:4], "int", size=2, endian="little", signed=FALSE)
  blockSize <- readBin(header[5:6], "int", size=2, endian="little", signed=FALSE)
  
  if (blockSize == 1970) {
    if (verbose) message("Block size: downscan")
  } else if (blockSize == 3200) {
    if (verbose) message("Block size: sidescan")
  } else {
    stop("Block size is not 'downscan' or 'sidescan'; Likely not an slg/sl2/sl3 file")
  }
  
  alwaysZero <- readBin(header[7:8], "int", size=2, endian="little", signed=FALSE)
  
  # yep, we're going to build a list the hard/slow way
  sl2_lst <- vector("list")
  idx <- 1
  pos <- 8 # keeping track of our place in the stream
  
  while (pos < length(dat)) {
    
    # if verbose mode echo a "." every 100 records
    if (verbose && ((idx %% 100) == 0)) cat(".")
    
    blockSize <- readBin(dat[(pos+29):(pos+30)], "int", size=2, endian="little", signed=FALSE)
    prevBlockSize <- readBin(dat[(pos+31):(pos+32)], "int", size=2, endian="little", signed=FALSE)
    packetSize <- readBin(dat[(pos+35):(pos+36)], "int", size=2, endian="little", signed=FALSE)
    frameIndex <- readBin(dat[(pos+37):(pos+40)], "int", size=4, endian="little")
    
    dplyr::data_frame(
      channel = readBin(dat[(pos+33):(pos+34)], "int", size=2,endian="little", signed=FALSE),
      upperLimit = readBin(dat[(pos+41):(pos+44)], "double", size=4, endian="little"),
      lowerLimit = readBin(dat[(pos+45):(pos+48)], "double", size=4, endian="little"),
      frequency = readBin(dat[(pos+54)], "int", size=1, endian="little", signed=FALSE),
      val1 = readBin(dat[(pos+55):(pos+56)], "int", size=2, endian="little"),
      val2 = readBin(dat[(pos+57):(pos+60)], "int", size=4, endian="little"),
      date = readBin(dat[(pos+61):(pos+64)], "int", size=4, endian="little"),
      
      waterDepth = readBin(dat[(pos+65):(pos+68)], "double", size=4, endian="little"),
      keelDepth = readBin(dat[(pos+69):(pos+72)], "double", size=4, endian="little"),
      
      byt1 = readBin(dat[(pos+73)], "int", size=1, endian="little", signed=FALSE),
      byt2 = readBin(dat[(pos+74)], "int", size=1, endian="little", signed=FALSE),
      val3 = readBin(dat[(pos+75):(pos+76)], "int", size=2, endian="little"),
      val4 = readBin(dat[(pos+77):(pos+78)], "int", size=2, endian="little"),
      val5 = readBin(dat[(pos+79):(pos+80)], "int", size=2, endian="little"),
      val6 = readBin(dat[(pos+81):(pos+84)], "double", size=4, endian="little"),
      val7 = readBin(dat[(pos+85):(pos+88)], "double", size=4, endian="little"),
      val8 = readBin(dat[(pos+89):(pos+92)], "double", size=4, endian="little"),
      val9 = readBin(dat[(pos+93):(pos+96)], "double", size=4, endian="little"),
      byt3 = readBin(dat[(pos+97)], "int", size=1, endian="little", signed=FALSE),
      byt4 = readBin(dat[(pos+98)], "int", size=1, endian="little", signed=FALSE),
      byt5 = readBin(dat[(pos+99)], "int", size=1, endian="little", signed=FALSE),
      byt6 = readBin(dat[(pos+100)], "int", size=1, endian="little", signed=FALSE),
      
      speedGps_kn = readBin(dat[(pos+101):(pos+104)], "double", size=4, endian="little"),
      temperature_c = readBin(dat[(pos+105):(pos+108)], "double", size=4, endian="little"),
      lng_enc = readBin(dat[(pos+109):(pos+112)], "integer", size=4, endian="little"),
      lat_enc = readBin(dat[(pos+113):(pos+116)], "integer", size=4, endian="little"),
      speedWater_kn = readBin(dat[(pos+117):(pos+120)], "double", size=4, endian="little"),
      track = readBin(dat[(pos+121):(pos+124)], "double", size=4, endian="little"),
      altitude = readBin(dat[(pos+125):(pos+128)], "double", size=4, endian="little"),
      heading = readBin(dat[(pos+129):(pos+132)], "double", size=4, endian="little"),
      timeOffset = readBin(dat[(pos+141):(pos+144)], "integer", size=4, endian="little"),

      sounding = readBin(dat[(pos+145):(pos+148)], size=4, "double", endian="little"),

      flags = list(
        dat[(pos+133):(pos+134)] %>%
          rawToBits() %>%
          as.logical() %>%
          set_names(
            c(
              "headingValid", "altitudeValid", sprintf("unk%d", 1:7),
              "gpsSpeedValid", "waterTempValid", "unk8", "positionValid",
              "unk9", "waterSpeedValid", "trackValid"
            )
          ) %>%
          .[c(1:2, 10:11, 13, 15:16)] %>%
          as.list() %>%
          purrr::flatten_df()
      )
    ) -> sl2_lst[[idx]]
    
    idx <- idx + 1
    
    pos <- pos + (packetSize+145-1)
    
  }
  
  if (verbose) cat("\n")
  
  dplyr::bind_rows(sl2_lst) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      channel = dplyr::case_when(
        channel == 0 ~ "Primary",
        channel == 1 ~ "Secondary",
        channel == 2 ~ "DSI (Downscan)",
        channel == 3 ~ "Left (Sidescan)",
        channel == 4 ~ "Right (Sidescan)",
        channel == 5 ~ "Composite",
        TRUE ~ "Other/invalid"
      )
    ) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      frequency = dplyr::case_when(
        frequency == 0 ~ "200 KHz",
        frequency == 1 ~ "50 KHz",
        frequency == 2 ~ "83 KHz",
        frequency == 4 ~ "800 KHz",
        frequency == 5 ~ "38 KHz",
        frequency == 6 ~ "28 KHz",
        frequency == 7 ~ "130-210 KHz",
        frequency == 8 ~ "90-150 KHz",
        frequency == 9 ~ "40-60 KHz",
        frequency == 10~ "25-45 KHz",
        TRUE ~ "Other/invalid"
      )
    ) %>%
    tidyr::unnest(flags)
  
}

data <- read_sl2("myfile.sl2")

#Conversions
#Lat/Lon
PolarEarthRadius = 6356752.3142
RadiansToDegrees = 180.0 / pi

data$longitude <- (data$lng_enc / PolarEarthRadius) * RadiansToDegrees
data$latitude <- ((2.0 * atan(exp(data$lat_enc / PolarEarthRadius))) - (pi / 2.0)) * RadiansToDegrees

#InternationalUnits
FeettoMeter = 0.3048

data$waterDepth_m <- data$waterDepth*FeettoMeter
data$keelDepth_m <- data$keelDepth*FeettoMeter
```

However, I am interested not only in the depth but also in the sonar image of the whole water column (all sounding points).

The sounding / bounce data seems to be recorded in the end of the package, but I have no idea of how to decode it.
[https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/SL2#:~:text=SL2%20is%20a%20binary%20format,downloaded%20on%20their%20web%20site](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/SL2#:%7E:text=SL2%20is%20a%20binary%20format,downloaded%20on%20their%20web%20site).

When I read the sl2 files in commercial software like ReefMaster I am capable of viewing the water column with the data read from the sl2 file so I guess that the information is inside, but I don't know how to decode it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out by myself.

The answer is not very pretty and the data is very heavy, so the function returns the memory allocation error more than often, but here it is:

```
read_sound <- function(path, verbose=TRUE) {
  
  #Unit transformations
  PolarEarthRadius = 6356752.3142
  RadiansToDegrees = 180.0 / pi
  FeettoMeter = 0.3048
  
  
  f <- file(path.expand(path), "rb")
  dat <- readBin(f, "raw", n = file.size(path.expand(path)), endian="little")
  close(f)
  
  # read in the header
  header <- readBin(dat, what = "raw", n = 10)
  
  format <- readBin(header[1:2], "int", size=2, endian="little", signed=FALSE)
  
  if (!(format %in% 1:3)) stop("Invalid 'format' in header; Likely not an slg/sl2/sl3 file")
  
  ok_formats <- c("slg", "sl2", "sl3")
  if (verbose) message("Format: ", ok_formats[format])
  
  version <- readBin(header[3:4], "int", size=2, endian="little", signed=FALSE)
  blockSize <- readBin(header[5:6], "int", size=2, endian="little", signed=FALSE)
  
  if (blockSize == 1970) {
    if (verbose) message("Block size: downscan")
  } else if (blockSize == 3200) {
    if (verbose) message("Block size: sidescan")
  } else {
    stop("Block size is not 'downscan' or 'sidescan'; Likely not an slg/sl2/sl3 file")
  }
  
  alwaysZero <- readBin(header[7:8], "int", size=2, endian="little", signed=FALSE)
  
  # yep, we're going to build a list the hard/slow way
  sound_list <- vector("list")
  idx <- 1
  pos <- 8 # keeping track of our place in the stream
  
  while (pos < length(dat)) {
    
    # if verbose mode echo a "." every 100 records
    if (verbose && ((idx %% 100) == 0)) cat(".")
    
    blockSize <- readBin(dat[(pos+29):(pos+30)], "int", size=2, endian="little", signed=FALSE)
    prevBlockSize <- readBin(dat[(pos+31):(pos+32)], "int", size=2, endian="little", signed=FALSE)
    packetSize <- readBin(dat[(pos+35):(pos+36)], "int", size=2, endian="little", signed=FALSE)
    frameIndex <- readBin(dat[(pos+37):(pos+40)], "int", size=4, endian="little")
    
    upperLimit = readBin(dat[(pos+41):(pos+44)], "double", size=4, endian="little")*FeettoMeter
    lowerLimit = readBin(dat[(pos+45):(pos+48)], "double", size=4, endian="little")*FeettoMeter
    
    dplyr::tibble(
      sounding = readBin(dat[(pos+145):(pos+145+packetSize)], n=packetSize, "integer", size=1, endian="little"),
      sounddepth = round(seq(upperLimit,lowerLimit,length.out = length(sounding)),2),
      longitude = readBin(dat[(pos+109):(pos+112)], "integer", size=4, endian="little")*RadiansToDegrees/PolarEarthRadius,
      latitude = (2*atan(readBin(dat[(pos+113):(pos+116)], "integer", size=4, endian="little")/ PolarEarthRadius)-(pi/2))*RadiansToDegrees,
      waterDepth_m = readBin(dat[(pos+65):(pos+68)], "double", size=4, endian="little")*FeettoMeter,
      ping = idx
    )-> sound_list[[idx]]
    
    idx <- idx + 1
    
    pos <- pos + (packetSize+145-1)
    
  }
  
  sound <- bind_rows(sound_list)
  sound$sounding <- ifelse(sound$sounding<0, sound$sounding+256, sound$sounding)   #The data is decoded adding +256 to negative values
  sound$ID <- cumsum(!duplicated(sound[3:4]))
  sound <- aggregate(. ~ sounddepth+ID, sound, mean)
  
  return(sound)
}
```